# Make all tables' columns have the same widths as the first table's

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an HTML5/jQuery Mobile/PHP website. The site has multiple separate tables, as I have decided to break the data across multiple pages (`<div data-role="page">`). The pages are populated with movie info (director, year, title), but that is irrelevant.

When the user clicks one of the headings, the tables will be sorted into ascending or descending order with a jQuery script. Initially, when the page loads, the user can see only the first page (first table), one such as in the image below. The user can browse the pages by clicking buttons and swiping left or right, thus seeing the other tables that all have their own dimensions.

[image]

If the user clicked the *director* heading, the table(s) would be sorted by director. As the data changes, however, the columns' widths change as well.

I could define the width of the columns into some fixed width, but in this case it's not possible since the user can define the columns that are visible: for example, he could make a new column *writer*, or even take the *director* column off, in which case fixed widths do not work well.

**My question is**, can I make the other tables' columns' widths the same as they were in the first table (or some other table, for the sake of generalization)? If I can, is there any solution that isn't dependent upon javascript?

The basic structure of the site:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-1">
        <table>...</table>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-2">
        <table>...</table>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page-3">
        <table>...</table>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: You could give each table row a width of 100% or some other value, so the color extends to the full width.

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest what color?

Comment: It seems like you're alternating colors with each row. Therefore, if you give each table row a fixed with (100%) then the background color of the row should extend to fill the width, giving you nice neat tables.

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest how does that have anything to do with my question? besides they already do; the body has some padding

Comment: Oh, never mind, you're not worried about each table having different widths, you're worrying about the columns. In that case, just give each column a fixed width.

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest as I mentioned in the post, giving each column a fixed width is out of the question, since the user can change the amount of columns and what information they hold.

Comment: Then give it a width that isn't fixed. In your javascript, you could set each column's width to 100 divided by the number of columns (percent), and update it every time a column is added or removed. `.style.width = (100/numCols).toString()+"%";`

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest I would also prefer not giving them equal widths. I like how the browser automatically distributes the widths in a smart way.

Comment: Can you post what the inside of each `<table>` looks like? That is, when loaded.

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest sure, here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/iC1YMWJ1 note that most of the classes and what not are generated by jQuery stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know any of your JavaScript, you'll have to replace the variables/arrays accordingly.

Iterate over each page, getting the width of the columns on that page. Save the largest width for that column (across pages)

For each page:

```
var colWidths = [];
for(var i=0, j=NumberOfPages; i<j; i++){
    for(var k=0, l=NumberOfColumns; k<l; k++){
        // check if the column is wider than the widest column for the previous pages
        if(colWidths[k]===undefined || colWidths[k] < $(...).width() ){
           // if so, change the widest width for that specific column to the current width
           colWidths[k] = $(...).width();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: replace `$(...)` with the element that is the table column. You will only need to get 1 of the table columns from each page, because within the table all the columns are the same width.

Then, because you want everything to equal to 100% in the end, you need to find the percentage of the total for each column.

```
var totalpx = 0;
// get combined widths of all the widest columns
for(var i=0, j=colWidths.length; i<j; i++){
    totalpx += colWidths[i];
}

// get percentage for each width from total
var percentages = [];
for(var i=0, j=colWidths.length; i<j; i++){
    percentages.push(colWidths[i]/totalpx);
}
```

Then, you give each column the appropriate percent from the percentages array.

```
.width = percentages[i]
```